# How to store a json Object serverside and respond with it

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to make a webpage and server where a user can enter in recipes and have them sent to (using JSON) the server and have the server store them in a file so that if the server is closed and reopened the user can request for something they've entered previously and can get it. I know how to send the JSON object both to the server and how to send the JSON object back to the client. I should note this can't use jquery.

What I need help with is how to store it in a file server side and get the contents from it later using a node.js server. They should all be stored in the same directory and I need to know how to get a list of the recipes in that directory. I've tried looking around but I can't seem to find the answer :(.

Example:

- user makes a recipies
  { name:"cheese n waffles"
  time:90,
  ingredients:"cheese, eggs and waffles",
  equipment:stove
  };
- Browser sends the JSON object to the server.
- Client asks for a list of the recipes stored.
- user asks for the recipe for spaghetti.

what I need help with:

- server gets a list of the recipes it has stored
- server takes the JSON object and stores it in /serverRootDir/recepiesStorage
- server accesses /serverRootDir/recepiesStorage and gets the spaghetti recipe

Comment: You can always store all the same data in a database and get data returned in JSON format from it.

Comment: There are lots of choices server side. Start by specifying what kind of server you have (ASP.NET, Node, ...)

Comment: Please remove 'solved' from your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a JSON based database such as [MondoDB](https://www.mongodb.com)

It takes some learming however implementing with a text file will eventually become much more work and will function poorly

Comment: ...or even a structured database (SQL).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I have solved the problem. I will be using:

To read a file (access a recipe): fs.readFileSync() or fs.readFile().

To save a file (update a recipe): fs.writeFileSync() or fs.writeFile().

To get an array of files in a directory (retrieve the list of recipes): fs.readdirSync() or fs.readdir().